# Does the ability to factor in polynomial time give you smooth numbers in the number field sieve?

Tags: number-field-sieve, sieve

I have read that despite strong connections between prime factorization and DLP an algorithm for the former does not imply the latter directly. But I was reading about the number field sieve and it seemed like the bottleneck was identifying smooth norms. Wouldn't an ultrafast prime factorization algorithm achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Being able to test for smooth norms quickly (e.g. polynomial time) is insufficient to quickly detect smooth norms in a large selection of candidates as the test must still be applied to a large number of candidates. Thus even if smooth norms could be identified in time $O(1)$, the log-asymptotic complexity of the number field sieve is unaffected. In fact sieving for smooth norms allows one to test $n$ candidates for $y$-smoothness in time and memory roughly $n\log\log y$ so that the parallelised smoothness test only takes an average $\log\log y$ work per candidate.

The bottleneck lies in the fact that $n$ cannot be too small or we will not find enough relations to produce a solvable linear algebra system. The cost to test the $n$ candidate norms is at best a second order effect (for example, the log asymptotic cost of the number field sieve is unchanged whether we test using sieving at cost $O(\log\log y)$ per candidate or ECM at cost $\exp((1+o(1))\sqrt{2\log y\log\log y})$ per candidate).

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't factoring larger smooth norms produce higher logs on the linear system which could precipitously drop n?

Comment: @IanCampbell No introducing a larger value of $y$ would make a greater proportion of candidates would succeed, but the number of successes required would also grow leading to an overall increase in $n$. Likewise, work of Croot, Granville, Peamantle and Tetali shows that there's no great hope of getting a solvable subsystem from a small subset of the relations.

Comment: One last question. What is the size of the smoothness bound? The best I've found is that it's x^(1/d) but I haven't found the optimal value of d. Are you sure about that complexity? The paper 'Smooth Numbers: Computational Number Theory and Beyond' States it as less than loglog(y)+uy on page 307. That's a huge difference if y is large

Comment: Also isn't the advantage in computational complexity of number and function field sieves compared to index calculus a smaller smoothness bound? That would imply higher n lower y which seems to imply the bottleneck is identifying smooth norms

Comment: The optimal smoothness bound is $y=\exp((2^{-1/2}+o(1))\sqrt{\log s\log\log s})$ where $s$ is the typical size of the numbers being tested for smoothness. This allows the optimal choice of $n$ (number of candidates) as $n=\exp((2^{1/2}+o(1))\sqrt{\log s\log\log s})$. In the GNFS $s=x^{2/d}n^{d/2}$ where $x$ is the number to be factored/modulus of the discrete logarithm and $d$ has to be optimised. Omitting the details this gives $y=\exp(((8/9)^{1/3}+o(1))(\log x)^{1/3}(\log\log x)^{2/3})$, $n=\exp(((64/9)^{1/3}+o(1))(\log x)^{1/3}(\log\log x)^{2/3})$

Comment: The advantage of GNFS (and  a similar phenomenon for FFS) is that $s$ is smaller than other methods, allowing both $y$ and $n$ to be smaller.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much!

Comment: One last question. I understand generally that the tradeoff in index-calculus-like algorithms is between the linear algebra at the end and the identification of smooth numbers at the beginning. Is there a minimum number on your factor base to get a solution, or is any factor base size acceptable, so long as it has enough relations?